# How to get additional drive capacity to recognize and support Ubuntu on a Windows (v10) machine

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a computer that came as a Windows 10 CPU from Dell.  I have been carrying 2 PCs with me for awhile: This "old" one from Dell with 500BG of storage (I'll call it 'hard drive') solely for old files and Microsoft apps (email, excel, Word, PowerPoint, etc), which is quite a bit of data for the 10+ years I have used a Windows system to do that.  I also carry a much cheaper HP that only has perhaps 250MB on it in total; while it can still boot in Windows mode I don't ever use it for anything other than Unix development.

I'd like to get both activities on one computer so I needn't carry 2.  But, recently when I tried to edit a file using EMACS I got an Ubuntu error that the disk space was exhausted (or some such).

I tried to make more space by shrinking the Windows partition that are not special or protected, but that yielded only a few megabytes. As I set it up, I gave Windows about 450MB of disk, Linux got about 30 GB, and the balance was needed for other things and/or is protected (like Windows swap partition).  One thing I clearly missed was that a Python/Django app pulls in a lot of lengthy libraries, leading to using up gigabytes fast.

So I am faced with three choices, with some questions about all of them.

1. Choice #1 is the add an outboard hard drive of, say, 500 GB, and then assign that to Linux.    But I can't figure out how that links into the file system (nor how to 'assign' that to Linux).  For example, my initial idea is copy all my unix stuff to a thumb drive, bring up Linux, and just paste that entire file below somewhere ("/"?).  But, how does the hardware and software map logical access to a physical home?  My fear here is I do this, I copy it below "/", and now I get all sorts of oddities as the internal system wants to place some directories on the new drive.  But how does that all work? (Plus, I need to lug around this USB3 disk drive all over creation.)
2. Another approach is to buy a new PC with 1 TB of hard drive, allocate 400 GB to Linux and 400 GB to Linux, giving lots of space to grow.  This keeps everything on one internal drive, with lots of space to grow.  You can buy CPUs with 1 TB of internal 'hard disk', and do what I just suggested using gparted if needed.(and even get Ubuntu factory installed from Dell and HP).

The problem with the obvious choice (#2) is this is pricey option.  But, it seems to be the most direct route.  If I went that way, are there tools for migration?

Which is the better route, and how do you make it happen?

Comment: Unlike Windows, Linux can be installed almost anyway you want.  Right now have root on a SSD, home on a 2TB HD, and media on a external 4TB drive.  Have had Ubuntu installed on internals and only external drive.  Can also install on an USB flash drive or even a SD card.  I am no expert on doing this, but linux seems to figure it out.  Main thing is to have big enough drive for your needs.   Most computers can use bigger drives than what is in them, and cheaper than new computer, most easy to replace.

Comment: How did you let it know the tree below root goes on one drive, while the 'home' directory is on another drive???

Comment: When installing, you are asked the size and where to put things when you use the 'something else' option for installs.  Be careful and check things over two or three times before committing, people have been known to install over windows or another important partition by mistake without any backup.  It thinks you know what you are doing.  Use google, many pages/videos how to install.